# How to find a local webserver without knowing the IP?

Tags: tcp, dns, udp, ip, multicast

I am doing a project where I have an embedded device running a webserver, and connected to a local WiFi network. Now I want my smartphone APP to connect to the webserver, but unless I chose to force a static IP to my embedded device, the app has no way of knowing what the IP of the webserver is.

I've looked into mDNS, but android doesn't support this, therefore it's a no go?

Any ideas of how I can connect my app to the embedded device?

(Google Chromecast does exactly this, but how?)

Comment: why mdns? either give the device a static IP, or use dhcp with a static mapping, and then the dns component becomes dead simple. and regardless, offtopic - not really a programming question.

Comment: @MarcB The device is something similar to a Chromecast, so no router setups. I can't predict which IP the device will get. I think Chromecast uses mDNS, and then they've implemented their own mDNS client on Android.. I disagree, even though there's no direct code involved, the question is about which programming technology to use to accomplish a specific goal.

Answer (score 0):

The way GoPro accomplishes this is by having the camera provide an access point, and then connecting directly to it from the client. For the embedded device, you could look at `hostapd`. You could store the SSID and pass phrase in the app somewhere, perhaps.

Comment: Yes exactly. And my device does the same - creates its own access point for the user to logon to for setting up the home WiFi network. Afterwards it connects to the home network, and here the problem arises, because I don't know which IP my device will get.

Comment: So you're just using hostapd as an intermediate step, to configure it's settings for client mode, on the home network? Do you have Bluetooth available on the device? You could skip all the above and just pass config data that way. Alternately, while the Android device is connected to the device (in access point mode), record the MAC of the other device, in your app. Then once both devices are back on the home network, do an ARP scan for the MAC. (arp -n on Linux ... on Android.... ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179299/scan-network-for-a-specific-mac-address-android maybe, is a start.)